# Internet Explorer not redirecting HTTP to HTTPS to a specific user

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, redirection, https

One of our users is trying to access a site that automatically re-directs the HTTP to a HTTPS domain, but it's not happening for her. She just gets a page cannot be displayed. However, if I "run as" my self the administrator, it redirects successfully. I tried resetting IE8 back to defaults but problem is still there. Someone mentioned that this could be a DNS issue.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because it works if you do a "Run As" I would suggest you recreate the windows profile.

1. Reboot the PC and log on as a local admin.
2. Move the users profile out of "Documents and Settings" and into some other folder (I like c:\olddata)
3. Then log in as the user and test the site.
4. If it works, move the data back into this newly created profile (only move stuff like MyDesktop, MyDocuments, Favorites, PST etc.. but not the rest of the garbage).

That should fix the problem...

After that I would suggest some maintenance on the PC. Clean up the disk with something like ATFCleaner. Defrag the PC with something like JKDefrag and then run "chkdsk c: /f." Allow the check to run on the next reboot.